# How to represent integers bigger as (10^6)! to use in equations to solve in java

Tags: java, biginteger, integer-overflow

How can we solve equations having N! constants in it , where N can be of range 1<=N<=10^6
BigInteger can only perform upto 128 bits right?

Even when one do logarithm on both sides, it leaves values bigger than BigInteger.

Comment: Where does it say "BigInteger can only do 128 bits"? To me, it says "arbitrary precision".

Comment: BigInteger is only limited by your available memory - unless this is the cause then it'll most likely be a bug with your code that's causing the issue. If you post more details we may be able to help.

Comment: how can one solve those equations(variables-2) having such a BigInteger constants without bruteforcing?

Answer (score 7):

No, `BigInteger` can handle arbitrary sizes of integer (limited by memory). From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html):

> Immutable **arbitrary-precision** integers.

(Emphasis mine.)

That's not to say that `BigInteger` will necessarily be the right answer to your requirements, but it's worth being aware of its *real* capabilities before deciding.

Answer (score 1):

> Even when one do logarithm on both sides, it leaves values bigger than BigInteger.

let N=10^6

```
log(N!) ~ NlogN - N [Stirling's approximation]

        ~ 13e6
```

this can (easily) fit in int

Comment: Sorry to say , but approximation can result wrong integral solutions to an equation right? so....

Comment: For N=100, Stirling's 2nd order approximation is accurate to > 99% and will not change your results noticeably for N > 1000, see e.g. (http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/math/stirling.html). You can also carry the approximation out to higher orders (see wikipedia).

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of BigInteger is limited to around 2 ^ 2.1 billion bits or about 256 MB. Given its used of `int` for bit lengths, this is unlikely to increase.